# Full citation using multibib?

Tags: citing, multibib

I am new to Latex and am using it for an academic paper.

As I need several bibliographies, I am using multibib which is working great, but I need full citations of the bibliography entries to appear at several point in the text as well. I have about 150 entries so I really don't fancy putting them all in manually...

Is there a way to do this? I read about the \bibentry package but I can't get it to work with multibib...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    \documentclass[11pt,oneside,a4paper]{report}
    \usepackage{multibib}
    \newcites{sec}{Secondary Sources}

    \begin{document}
    Blablablabla \fullcitation-from-either-bibliography blablabla

    \bibliographystyle{acm}
    \renewcommand\bibname{Primary Sources}
    \bibliography{pri}

    \bibliographystylesec{acm}
    \bibliographysec{sec}

    \end{document}
```